# Como remover traços internos de um <SELECT> no Firefox

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, firefox

Mais uma vez acabo de perceber que o Firefox está colocando "estilizações adicionais" nos meus inputs.

Dessa vez, no `<select>`, quando eu clico em cima dele pra selecionar uma opção, sempre aparece um tracejado interno:

[image: Tracejado no input do firefox]

[image: Tracejado no input do firefox]

Isso é algo que acontece especificamente no Firefox. Tem como remover esses tracinhos que estão aparecendo quando seleciono o `<select>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Windows isso não ocorre, ao menos não no Firefox, estou *quase certo* de que isto é uma situação que ***ocorre no Ubuntu*** ou no **ambiente gráfico especifico**, pois os controles renderizados no navegador são "parcialmente" gerados a partir do "sistema operacional" o que provavelmente não permitirá uma customização total.

Conforme exemplo da outra pergunta no Windows, para testar **clique em:**

```css
.form-control
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    min-height: 57px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    transition: border-color .1s linear;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 select.form-control {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
         appearance: none; /*provavelmente será implementado no futuro*/

    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMzA2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMzA2cHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMDYgMzA2IiBzdHlsZT0iZW5hYmxlLWJhY2tncm91bmQ6bmV3IDAgMCAzMDYgMzA2OyIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PGc+PHBvbHlnb24gcG9pbnRzPSIyNzAuMyw1OC42NSAxNTMsMTc1Ljk1IDM1LjcsNTguNjUgMCw5NC4zNSAxNTMsMjQ3LjM1IDMwNiw5NC4zNSIvPjwvZz48L3N2Zz4=) center right no-repeat;

   background-size: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
<option>Selecione...</option>
<option>Masculino</option>
<option>Feminino</option>
</select>
```

O resultado no Firefox em Windows foi:

[image: firefox]

> **Nota:** No Windows o único momento que foi mostrado o pontilhado foi quando usei o <kbd>Tab</kbd> para navegar

---

### Técnicas para remover o "outline" no Firefox

> **Nota:** É bem provável que essas técnicas **funcionem melhor** quando aplicada para links como: `<a href="...">foo bar</a>`

Você pode experimentar o:

```
select.form-control, select.form-control:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Clique abaixo **para testar:**

```css
select.form-control
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

select.form-control, select.form-control:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
<option>Selecione...</option>
<option>Masculino</option>
<option>Feminino</option>
</select>
```

---

Ou `moz-focusring` com "algum" efeito:

```
select.form-control:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Clique abaixo **para testar:**

```css
select.form-control:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}

select.form-control
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
<option>Selecione...</option>
<option>Masculino</option>
<option>Feminino</option>
</select>
```

---

Ou o seletor `-moz-focus-inner`, este foi o que funcionou melhor, ao menos com navegação via <kbd>Tab</kbd> teve o efeito desejado, no entanto no Debian com Lxde não funcionou:

```
select.form-control::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

Clique abaixo **para testar:**

```css
select.form-control::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}

select.form-control
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
<option>Selecione...</option>
<option>Masculino</option>
<option>Feminino</option>
</select>
```

---

### Concluindo

Ou seja creio eu não que não exista técnica garantida, pois depende do **sistema operacional**, mesmo técnicas como `moz-focusring` poderão não chegar ao resultado desejado ou causar até outro efeito em diferentes sistemas operacionais, pois não é possível customizar por por completo.

Leve em consideração que esse pontilhado pode até ajudar o usuário e não incomoda tanto.

Comment: Se liga no bagulho: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfeUb.png

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei a resposta

Comment: @WallaceMaxters editei novamente a resposta, teste todos exemplos em *"Técnicas para remover o "outline" no Firefox"*, creio que o `select.form-control::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}` será o que irá chegar mais perto.

Comment: Legal um downvote free, sendo a unica resposta técnica de fato. Seja lá quem for poderia explicar aonde foi que eu errei ou o que eu fiz de errado. Pra que eu possa melhorar.

Comment: Ué, eu upei... Será que bugou no celular?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters na verdade eu suspeito de quem seja, infelizmente é um usuário que não sabe levar criticas construtivas e sai dando votos por empatia e antipatia

Comment: Teste: http://jsfiddle.net/4np7vroh/1/

Comment: Dando o mesmo problema, hahahahahaha... parece que é algo do sistema operacional mesmo!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, no Debian também ocorre, só o hack com text-shadow "resolveu", como descrevi na resposta nenhuma técnica é 100% garantida. Mas ainda estou fazendo testes e lendo algumas coisas na comunidade Mozilla

Comment: @WallaceMaxters > Leve em consideração que esse pontilhado pode até ajudar o usuário e não incomoda tanto, já que só ocorre no momento do foco.

Answer (score 3):

[Esse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468615/3444041) estilo pode resolver alguns comportamentos padrão:

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

No OS não aconteceu o mesmo problema, nem no Firefox.

Comment: Esse caso parece ter amenizado um pouco do problema.

Comment: Foi você quem deu o downvote na minha resposta? Não tenho nada contra, mas poderia justificar? Fico agradecido, só gostaria de saber aonde falhei.

Comment: [Não foi](https://imgur.com/MD8yprB). Por que seria @GuilhermeNascimento ?

Comment: @LucasCosta também não sei, gostaria de saber a motivação apenas. Obrigado por responder. PS: bonito Mac, é "retina"?

Comment: Tudo bem, de vez em quando recebo alguns downvotes anonimos. Pra ser honesto eu acho que deveria ser obrigatorio deixar um comentario apos o downvote.

Comment: hahahah Retina sim, o 2017... usa tb @GuilhermeNascimento?

Comment: Não estou ainda nesse nivel, mas espero que ano que vem melhore as coisas pra mim e talvez eu consiga dar entrada em um :D

Comment: So dou uma diga, nao compre no Brazil (nao estou falando necessariamente dos EUA) hehe

Answer (score 3):

Ja existe uma resposta dizendo algo parecido, mas complementando:

```css
.form-control-border {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #555555;
  border-color: #fff;
    }
.form-control-bg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #fff;
    }
.form-control-moz {
 
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #555555;
  
  background-color: -moz-Combobox;
  color: -moz-ComboboxText;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
}
.form-control-n{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #555555;
}
```

```html
<select class='form-control-border'>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>

<select class='form-control-bg'>
 <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>

<select class='form-control-moz'>
 <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>

<select class='form-control-n'>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Repare que ao adicionar qualquer estilo de `borda` e `background` sobre um `select`, o pontilhado interno aparece no momento do `focus`.

1 - Veja que no select de classname `'.form-control-n'` não há borda pontilhada em focus.

2 - No `'.form-control-moz'` o pontilhado foi para as pontas.

3 - E nos demais onde há modificação da propriedade `background` e `border` ha o pontilhado no meio.

Isso ocore porque dentro de `background-color` há um estilo do firefox `-moz-Combobox` e também um estilo chamado `'-moz-appearance: menulist'`, que, a conclusão que cheguei foi que esses dois estilos são responsáveis por gerar esse tracejado.

Não consegui sobrepor esses estilos de forma nenhuma, caso consiga atualizo a resposta.

Ambiente de teste:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 
Firefox Quantun.
```

Comment: Foi você quem deu o downvote na minha resposta? Não tenho nada contra, mas poderia justificar? Fico agradecido, só gostaria de saber aonde falhei.